# Chrome `position:fixed; bottom: 0;` obscured by Android UI

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser

I have an issue with the following code on Android Chrome. The navigation bars are covering up the element at the bottom of the page.

```
#test{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

### Desktop Chrome (correct)

[image]

### Android Chrome:

[image: Android Chrome on Pixel 2]

Here is a link to the demo:
https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/EMNaVg

I know that I can increase the `bottom: $amount` to make it show, but then on other browsers the message won't be flush with the bottom of the browser.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: why are you using relative position in the html and body tag?

Comment: @TheDev you can remove it, it doesn't affect `position:fixed;`

Comment: And if you scroll back/hide browser toolbar does element gets to it's actual bottom position?

Comment: @Justinas no – it is not possible to scroll the page, and the UI won't hide, even when tapping other parts of the screen. It may just be a bug... I've submitted it as feedback within the Chrome App

Comment: set the bottom to env(safe-area-inset-bottom) instead of 0

Answer (score 3):

I've tried a solution that I founded in [this articule](https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/)

It's a mix between css and javascript.

First in the css class of the container of the body itself you should define the height property like this:

```
height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
```

The vh unit is 1% of the initial containing block, so we can calculate the actual viewport height multiplying our "custom unit" by 100.

Now, the custom unit comes from a javascript variable in the html.

```
let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`;
```

In the code above the vh unit is calculated getting the initial viewport size by 1% of it. Then the result is passed to the stylesheet.

And there you go.

The link offers a more detailed explanation and it also show how to handle screen resizing.

Comment: Thanks elijah, I'm familiar with this. Does it still work with `position: fixed` though? Also, you have a little typo, if should be `...1vh) * 100);` so no `vh` on the second `100`

Comment: Thanks Djave, I've edited the answer. I haven't tested it with position: fixed, will try it and let you know

Comment: Works well for me, iPhone Safari and Android Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    Box-sizing: Border-box;
}
    body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
```

Comment: This does not change anything. `position: fixed;` doesn't care about the body or html padding :(